# Is the performance of a neural network, which was trained with encrypted data and weights, affected if the weights are decrypted?

Tags: neural-networks, training, performance, weights

Suppose that a neural network is trained with encrypted (for example, with [homomorphic encryption](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/2018/0547.pdf) and, more precisely, with the [Paillier partial scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem)) data. Moreover, suppose that it is also trained with encrypted weights.

If the neural network's weights are decrypted, is the performance of the neural network theoretically preserved or affected?

Comment: I tried to clarify your question and post. Please, make sure that it's consistent with your original question/intentions. Also, please, next time, try to ask a clearer question by also providing more context (including links to relevant resources).